# django-filepicker filepicker.io with in CreateView

Tags: django, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I am using [django-filepicker](https://github.com/Ink/django-filepicker) to integrate filepicker.io into my Django app.

Now, I have 2 questions:

**Field Rendering**

I integrated the model field as:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
fpfile = django_filepicker.models.FPFileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

I then used a generic CreateView on the Post Model:

```
class PostCreate(generic.edit.CreateView):
```

specifying `fields = [..,'fpfile']` in the PostCreate class

having syncdb'ed and specified the settings as:

```
FILEPICKER_API_KEY = '...'

CWD = os.getcwd()

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CWD, 'media')
```

The fpfile field renders but only as textview, although the html reads:

```
<label for="id_fpfile">Fpfile:</label>
<input data-fp-apikey="..." data-fp-mimetypes="*/*" id="id_fpfile" name="fpfile" type="filepicker-dragdrop">
```

What is missing to have the filepicker widget get rendered here? Are there problem with using it inside generic class-based views? The field in fact renders correctly into a "Choose File" field in the admin portal.

**S3 File Uploads**

Having specified all required S3 information through the filepicker dashboard, should I additionally change the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ...` fields of the app's settings.py ?

Answer (score 1):

About your second question: **S3 settings**. You can provide them by using additional_params:

```
fpfile = django_filepicker.models.FPFileField(additional_params={
    'data-fp-option-services': 'COMPUTER, GMAIL, FACEBOOK',
    'data-fp-store-location': 'S3',
    'data-fp-store-path': 'some_folder',
})
```

Here are more possible values you may find in there https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets in the section additional_params ;)